# Using Mouseover to change colour of the FilledCurve

Tags: graphics, dynamic

I would like to **change colour** of the `FilledCurve` and **display little table** when mouse pointer goes over the area between curves. My code is shown below

```
pts = {{0, 1}, {-1, -(1/2)}, {1, -(1/2)}};
table = Grid[{{a, b, c}, {x, y^2, z^3}}, Frame -> All];

Tooltip[Mouseover @@ (Graphics[{#, 
   FilledCurve[{{Line[2 pts]}, {Line[pts]}}]}] & /@ {Red, 
 Green}), table]
```

The problem is that the colour should change only if the mouse pointer lies in the red region (region between curves) of the graphic object, but right now the colour changes and table display even if mouse is in the white region outside the curves.
I will be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
pts = {{0, 1}, {-1, -(1/2)}, {1, -(1/2)}};
table = Grid[{{a, b, c}, {x, y^2, z^3}}, Frame -> All];

With[
 {fc = FilledCurve[{{Line[2 pts]}, {Line[pts]}}]},
 Graphics[Mouseover[{Red, fc}, Tooltip[{Green, fc}, table]]]]
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!